# Detect when a process has exited (not crashed)

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm trying to run some code when notepad.exe has been closed gracefully (by the user, as opposed to crashed or shutdown by the OS) using Win32 events so I can implement an autosave.

If I have an `IntPtr` for a running notepad.exe process handle, how can I do this?

Comment: *I have an IntPtr to an instance* - what is "instance" ? what is `IntPtr` you have ?

Comment: If you have a processId Process.GetProcessById() will give you an object with a blocking wait method or an exited event.

Comment: it wont tell you inadvance if it is closing, only if it has closed and is too late

Comment: @AlexK. would that enable me to tell a crash from a graceful (user controlled) exit?

Comment: @mcintyre321 - no, unclear what is *IntPtr to an instance* (process handle ? process id ?). anyway you need got process handle and pass it to any wait function

Comment: @RbMm is that more clear?

Comment: @BugFinder are you saying that there is no way to tell the graceful user controlled exit apart from crashed/killed exit?

Comment: use this handle in any wait api - `WaitForSingleObjectEx`, `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`, `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx` - when handle is signaled - process exit

Comment: @mcintyre321 I dont think so, you can test if a process is responding, and still there, but I dont think you can easily determine if it was closed or terminated by task manager etc. I think you can only really determine the fact its not there any more

Comment: after we detect that process exit (by waiting on it handle) we can call `GetExitCodeProcess`. if *notepad.exe* exit normally will 0 as exit code, if it terminated or crashed - this in general undefined but almost always not 0

Comment: When you end a task using Task Manager, it will try to perform a graceful shutdown of the target first. This shutdown is indistinguishable from a user manually closing the application. Anyway, this really sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), where *Y* is not solvable.

Comment: @IInspectable for my purposes, that's fine. If the user gracefully shuts down then I don't need to worry about autosave. If you do a taskkill /f you get a non 0 exit code

Comment: The typical graceful shutdown sends `WM_CLOSE` to an application's windows. One could also post `WM_QUIT` to its threads, assuming there's a message loop on one of them, but I don't think anything does that in practice. Thus generally graceful shutdown is limited to applications that have windows.

Comment: For consoles, the system pretends that the allocating process (if it's still running) is the window owner. The task manager and taskkill.exe support killing this fake owner gracefully via `WM_CLOSE`. The console in turn sends `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` to all attached processes, which have 5 seconds to exit before getting forcefully terminated. For other process attached to a console, in principle one could try attaching to the console and getting the window handle via `AttachConsole` and `GetConsoleWindow`. However, the task manager and taskkill.exe do not do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no process property you can query to see if a process crashed or was terminated. The best you can do is to check the exit code, if it is 0 then the process probably exited after successfully completing its "action".

MSDN has [a example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode(v=vs.110).aspx) that uses `WaitForExit` and the `ExitCode` property on a child process...